# Philips UT102 Bluetooth Headset Mic not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am using the Philips UT102 Bluetooth Headset with Mic. Mint is not detecting its input source Mic over Bluetooth but only the earphone is working. I was wondering if it is a broken piece I got from Amazon, but is not.

[image]

[image]

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
Device 45:E6:44:AA:20:34 45-E6-44-AA-20-34
Device 4C:1E:17:38:5B:F5 4C-1E-17-38-5B-F5
Device 0B:F3:C9:A9:3D:10 0B-F3-C9-A9-3D-10
Device F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7 Philips UT102

$ bluetoothctl info
Device F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7 (public)
    Name: Philips UT102
    Alias: Philips UT102
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v03E0p300Ad0100


$ pacmd list-sources
  * index: 3
    name: <bluez_sink.F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7.a2dp_sink.monitor>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 48.22 ms
    monitor_of: 3
    card: 3 <bluez_card.F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7>
    module: 29
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Philips UT102"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.string = "F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Philips UT102"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
```

I see **headset-input available: no** from `pacmd info`. Also, not changing to **HSP/HFP** profile. Why so only on Linux?

```
index: 3
    name: <bluez_card.F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 29
    properties:
        device.description = "Philips UT102"
        device.string = "F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Philips UT102"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    profiles:
        a2dp_source: High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source) (priority 20, available: no)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: yes)
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <a2dp_sink>
    sinks:
        bluez_sink.F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7.a2dp_sink/#3: Philips UT102
    sources:
        bluez_sink.F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7.a2dp_sink.monitor/#3: Monitor of Philips UT102
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
```

Some error log:

```
$ journalctl -u bluetooth | grep -E 'F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7|F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7'
May 16 16:44:04 desk bluetoothd[686]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7: Device or resource busy
May 16 16:44:07 desk bluetoothd[686]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7/sep1/fd0: fd(43) ready
May 16 16:56:53 desk bluetoothd[720]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7: Device or resource busy
May 16 16:56:56 desk bluetoothd[720]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
May 16 17:06:46 desk bluetoothd[773]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7: Device or resource busy
May 16 17:06:49 desk bluetoothd[773]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
May 16 18:04:49 desk bluetoothd[668]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7/fd0: fd(43) ready
May 16 18:42:27 desk bluetoothd[668]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:00:CF:E7: Device or resource busy
May 16 18:42:30 desk bluetoothd[668]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_04_00_CF_E7/sep1/fd1: fd(42) ready


$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 
           Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: H110M-D v: Rev X.0x serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0310 
           date: 02/01/2016 
Battery:   Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Keyboard charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-6098P bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Skylake-S rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 28800 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 510 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER] vendor: Gigabyte driver: nvidia v: 460.73.01 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 2560x1080~60Hz, 2560x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.73.01 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-73-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: NetGear WNA1000Mv2 802.11bgn [Realtek RTL8188CUS] type: USB driver: rtl8192cu bus ID: 1-7:3 
           IF: wlx506a03eae99b state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.02 TiB used: 10.20 GiB (1.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: SanDisk model: SDSSDA120G size: 111.79 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Toshiba model: DT01ACA100 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 109.04 GiB used: 10.19 GiB (9.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: nvidia temp: 38 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
Info:      Processes: 224 Uptime: 1m Memory: 15.53 GiB used: 1.07 GiB (6.9%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Does the above error mean the Linux system is not allowing the headset to switch to HSP/HFP profile or some other bug?.

**To test it further, I installed Windows 10 on the same machine and the Bluetooth Mic is working fine for the input profile.**

[image]

**Tested it using Zoom test chat and both are working:**

[image]

Does anyone know any workaround for this or the only solution is to buy a new bluetooth headset with a mic that works with Linux? :)

Comment: Mint isn't an official Ubuntu derivative and is off-topic here.

Comment: FYI, I tested this on Ubuntu, the same issue there.

Comment: No doubt, but still off-topic.

Comment: Does this become on-topic if I repost with the ubuntu command line result?

Comment: Not up to me to decide.